TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate file name opentelemetry/proto/common/v1/common.proto in Docker
I'm encountering an issue when trying to build my Docker image. The error message I receive is:
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate file name opentelemetry/proto/common/v1/common.proto

This error occurs during the run time. Below is my requirements.txt file:
numpy~=1.26.4
oauthlib==3.2.2
openai==1.12.0
pandas==1.5.3
pandas-stubs==1.2.0.39
requests==2.32.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
uvicorn==0.23.0
anyio==3.5.0
tenacity==8.2.3
plotly==5.13.0
scipy
scikit-learn
pydantic~=1.10.12
tiktoken==0.5.2
regex
PyPDF2==3.0.1
docx2txt==0.8
python-docx==0.8.11
python-multipart==0.0.9
pybase64==1.2.3
slowapi==0.1.8
nltk==3.8.1
Jinja2==3.1.4
pytailwindcss==0.1.4
pdf2image==1.16.3
pypdf==3.17.0
langchain==0.1.14
langchain-community==0.0.30
langchain-openai==0.0.4
typing_extensions==4.8.0
unstructured==0.6.11
python-pptx==0.6.23
APScheduler==3.10.4
python-socketio==5.8.0
websockets==11.0.3
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.44.0
pandasai==2.1
bs4==0.0.1
matplotlib==3.7.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
PyMySQL==1.1.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.49
pypandoc-binary==1.12
qdrant-client==1.9.1
chromadb==0.5.0
protobuf==4.25.3


from pandasai.ee.vectorstores.pinecone import Pinecone  
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandasai/ee/vectorstores/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from .chroma import ChromaDB
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandasai/ee/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 5, in <module>   
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   import chromadb 
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 5, in <module> 
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from chromadb.auth.token_authn import TokenTransportHeader  usw2-dev-taskgpt-core-cn
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/auth/token_authn/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from chromadb.telemetry.opentelemetry import (
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter  
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/opentelemetry/exporter/otlp/proto/grpc/trace_exporter/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>   
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.common.trace_encoder import (
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/opentelemetry/exporter/otlp/proto/common/trace_encoder.py", line 16, in <module>   June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.common._internal.trace_encoder import (
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/opentelemetry/exporter/otlp/proto/common/_internal/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   from opentelemetry.proto.common.v1.common_pb2 import (  
June 07, 2024 at 13:08 (UTC+5:30)   File "/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/opentelemetry/proto/common/v1/common_pb2.py", line 17, in <module>



Have you found the solution of it?

No, @Anand, I have not found the solution yet.

For me newrelic library was causing issue, I downgraded it. You need to check which of the library is causing opentelemetry issue
